# Can we use aws s3api put-object-acl --acl to change the permission to write?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

`aws --endpoint-url=https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net s3api put-object-acl --bucket mytestbucket  --key foo.txt  --acl public-read-write`

`aws --endpoint-url=https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net s3api get-object-acl --bucket mytestbucket  --key foo.txt`

```
{
    "Owner": {
        "DisplayName": "b25ce81dcaa1498db3d1c802b3fdd",
        "ID": "b25ce81dcaa1498db3d1c802b3fdd"
    },
    "Grants": [
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "Type": "Group",
                "URI": "ttp://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers"
            },
            "Permission": "READ"
        },
        {
            "Grantee": {
                "Type": "CanonicalUser",
                "DisplayName": "b25ce81dcaa1498db3d1c802b3fdd",
                "ID": "b25ce81dcaa1498db3d1c802b3fdd"
            },
            "Permission": "FULL_CONTROL"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I added some basic formatting to your question so it's easier to read. Please review [Stack Overflow's formatting documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so you can do this yourself next time. But your question still isn't clear. Please [edit] it and add some context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ACLs to grant specific accounts `WRITE` permission is only possible at the bucket level.  Objects can still be granted `PUBLIC-READ-WRITE` permissions using a canned ACL, but only `READ` permissions will be set.

Object ACLs are limited to granting specific accounts `READ`, `READ_ACP` (read ACL), or `WRITE_ACP` (write ACL) permissions, and `FULL_CONTROL` grants all three permissions. That said, the CLI commands you are issuing up there are correct, and AWS has the same limitations for object ACLs.

For more information on creating object ACLs, [see the API documentation](https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/crs-api-reference.html#create-an-acl-for-an-object).

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, and when I create an object (using `putObject([ 'ACL' => 'private', Bucket' => '...' , Key => '...', 'Body' => '...'])` ) in a private mode and i'm still getting the same permission `FULL_CONTROLL` as above